# Choosing right resolver for certain domain

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I'ts possible to let resolver to select a specific resolv for particular domain?

For example i have, in my resolv:

```
search www.huaweimobilewifi.com mycompany.domain
nameserver 192.168.8.1 <- my mobile wifi
nameserver 10.x.y.z <- my company
nameserver 10.j.k.q <- my comany
```

I need to resolve every domain in mycompany.domain to be resolved by company dns and every other domain resolved by mobile nameserver

Comment: Various solutions on other stack exchange sites, http://superuser.com/questions/38736/how-can-i-set-up-linux-to-use-a-different-dns-server-for-a-certain-domain - http://serverfault.com/questions/391914/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-specific-dns-for-a-specific-domain - generally, you run your own local caching DNS server, point resolv.conf at it, and configure it to handle where to send requests.